# Execute PHP script without including in current file

Tags: php

Is there a way to execute a different php file without having to include it in the current executing php file?
Can shell_exec help?

Comment: What do you want to achieve ? Please explain more in question.

Comment: [Sure](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.usage.php)

Comment: @Shyam Why would he use a cron job?

Comment: @Shrey just explain what's the objective, is getting the thing done complex way good?

Comment: @GoldunoSupport Without understanding the context, How did you decide for yourself that this is the complex way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the exec function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

e.g.

```
exec ('php -f /path/to/file.php',$output,$return);
```